# Some site names are truncated in the grid of sites

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

There are several sites whose names are truncated currently on the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) at least in grid view:

- Retrocomputin
- ExpressionEng Answers
- Software Recommendat
- Hardware Recommendat
- Software Quality Assurance &

The first 4 sites have one or more letters cut off:

[image: Retrocomputin Image]

For the last site, it's an entire word that is cut off (but the tops of letters are visible):

[image: Software Quality Assurance &]

I am in Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) on Mac 10.7.5.

This also happens in mobile Safari.

Comment: What browser and what OS (and versions)? - these are things you should *always* provide when reporting such bugs (and if you encounter on multiple browsers/oses - also say so).

Comment: @Oded Thanks, I just added it.

Comment: "Software Quality Assurance & Testing" is also truncated.

Comment: @JonasCz It doesn't follow the same pattern as the others, so I missed it the first time around. Thanks to your comment, I have added it and another screenshot.

Comment: @Laurel also add, this is happening in the All Sites [Grid view](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#)

Comment: @Arulkumar Added, thanks. It's one of those things where I saw the button, but never bothered to try pressing it `:P`.